# Need to ensure a function returns data before i call next function

Tags: angular

I have a function that retrieves some data from a local storage and then i need to pass it to another function. In my case this seems to be unreliable as i might call the second function before the data arrives and then i don't get the result as expected. Below is the code i am calling

```
const filterResult = this.gridFilterService.getPreviousFilter(this.gridGuid)
this.applyPreviousFilter(filterResult)
```

in here is the function which i call to get the data from Local Storage

```
  // Retrive the current stored Filters in Local store which matches gridGuid
    getPreviousFilter(gridGuid : string): IAgGridSearchFilterResult {
        const gridFilters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridFilters'));
        if (gridFilters) {
            const activeFilters: any = gridFilters.find(x => x.gridGuid === gridGuid)
            if (activeFilters) {
                return activeFilters
            }
        }
    }
```

So what can i do to ensure i have a response before i call the

```
this.applyPreviousFilter(filterResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically nothing!

Execution of code is line by line. So `this.applyPreviousFilter(filterResult)` will not get called until the previous line's execution has executed.

In your case, however, not all code paths in the `getPreviousFilter` function are returning a value. That is, `return activeFilters`, is called only in a double nested if statement.

You need to find a way to return data in corresponding else statements for both ifs. So that way, you are sure that `getPreviousFilter` will always return a value.

So you should have something like instead for the localStorage function:

```js
// Retrieve the current stored Filters in Local store which matches gridGuid
getPreviousFilter(gridGuid: string): IAgGridSearchFilterResult {
  const gridFilters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridFilters'));
  if (gridFilters) {
    const activeFilters: any = gridFilters.find((x) => x.gridGuid === gridGuid);
    if (activeFilters) {
      return activeFilters;
    } else {
      // uncomment the following line and return some default value
      // return defaultFilters;
    }
  } else {
    // uncomment the following line and return some default value
    // return defaultFilters;
  }
}
```

##### More Info

> So what can i do to ensure i have a response before i call the
>
> ```js
> this.applyPreviousFilter(filterResult)
> ```

The only case where you would have needed to do something to ensure such would have been if there are asynchronous calls in the previous function. Then using `async` and `await` would have been okay.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, everything seems to be sync code, so it already should be working sequentially (although as @obumuneme-nwabude mentioned in his answer, the `getPreviousFilter` method could not return the data).

You could change the strategy, making the `getPreviousFilter` method send the data through a subject, which would be used to trigger the `applyPreviousFilter` method when there's actual data.

But if your concern is more about the `applyPreviousFilter` method being called by itself in another part of the code in the near future, maybe you could turn it into a private method inside the service and create a public method to encapsulate both calls, which would assure they would always be run together.

Cheers!

Comment: even so as i assumed the code is sync it seems to not always wait for it to complete before some other parts run.  So for now i was only able to solve some of the issues i was facing by using setTimeout. If i cant find the real issue i guess i will have to try to convert those functions to an async call

Comment: When does this code triggers? Is it on a lifecycle hook or a template event? As mentioned before, sometimes your storage method doesn't return which could be the reason other code lines are being executed before applying the filters...but it could also be because these and other behaviors are attached to parallel async events. In that case, you would need to reorganize the way your code is being triggered, in order to achieve the proper execution flow.